# Need help for my thesis project: electron, express & sqlite3

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, express, electron

i'm currently working on my thesis project which consists of an educational desktop videogame for public and private schools in my city.

I also really like electron so i thought it would be a nice idea to make my app using it, however it's here when the problem starts. My university demands that all apps must use a relational database (SQL) and not non-relational db like MongoDB. Since the database i'll have it's relative small i chose SQLite.

For some reason i began to get a certain error:

```
C:\Users\Alejandro\Documents\Proyectos\express\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\electron-v1.4-win32-ia32\node_sqlite3.node
```

After some research i found out that the reason was because electron executes on the client side and databases can only work on server side, to solve this issue i installed express on my app to execute a server in the background while electron executes the client (local client-server desktop app).

After some coding this was the result:

- Main.js (Electron code changes)

  ```
  const express = require('./resources/express')
  const electron = require('electron')

  // Module to control application life.
  const app = electron.app

  // Module to create native browser window.
  const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow

  const path = require('path')
  const url = require('url')

  // Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.

  let mainWindow 

  function createWindow () {
   // Create the browser window.
   mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})
   // and load the index.html of the app.
   mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:8080/')

  // Emitted when the window is closed.

  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
   console.log('app server is closing')
   express.closeServer()
   mainWindow = null
   })
  }
  ```
- Express.js (Express code):

  ```
  const http = require('http')
  const express = require('express')
  const dbmanager = require('./dbmanager.js')

  app = express()

  app.set('view engine', 'pug')

  app.get('/',function(request, response){
   console.log('server started :D')
   response.end()
  })

  app.get('/checktable',function(request, response){
   dbmanager.createTable()
   response.redirect('/receive')
  })

  app.get('/receive',function(request, response){
   dbmanager.selectAll(function(err,data){
    data.forEach(function(row){
     console.log(row.id + " " + row.name + "Edad: " + row.age)
    })
   response.render('index', { title: 'Usuario', message: data[0].name + " " + data[0].last })
   response.end()
   })
  })

  var server = http.createServer(app).listen(8080)

  var serverManager = {}

  serverManager.closeServer = function(){// This executes
   console.log('This is executing')
   console.log('Server should close now')
   server.close()
  }

  module.exports = serverManager
  ```
- dbmanager.js (SQLite queries)

  ```
  var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose()
  var db = new sqlite3.Database('memory')

  var queryManager = {}

  queryManager.createTable = function(){
   db.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS students (id int, name TEXT,last TEXT, age int)")
  }

  queryManager.deleteTable = function(){
   db.run('DROP TABLE students')
  }

  queryManager.insertStudent = function(student){
   var stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO students VALUES (?,?,?,?)")
   stmt.run(student.id,student.name,student.last,student.age)
   stmt.finalize()
   console.log('Insert Successful')
  }

  queryManager.selectAll = function(callback){
   db.all('SELECT * FROM students', function(err,rows){
    if(err)
    {
     throw err;
    }
    else
    {
     callback(null, rows);
    }
   })
  }

  module.exports= queryManager
  ```
- Index.pug (view)

  ```
   html
    head
   title= title
  body
   table#table
   h1= message
  ```

Before trying to execute the entire app i tried only executing the server and it worked.

I modified the npm start line from  "electron ." to "electron . && node ./resources/express.js" so i could execute both the client and the server.

At that moment i commented all the lines related to the dbmanager.js to test if the client and server were working.

Needing to close the server at the moment the app windows was close i created a function to close the server when window close funcion is called, but it doesn't.

That's the first problem. The second problem shows up when i undo the comment on the dbmanager lines, i get the same error as before:

```
 'C:\Users\Alejandro\Documents\Proyectos\express\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\electron-v1.4-win32-ia32\node_sqlite3.node'
```

Am i doing something wrong? Please i really need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're spinning up an Express server on the same machine as your Electron app, if your server can access a local database then what makes you think your app can't? You don't need an Express server. To use the `sqlite3` module in an Electron app you just have to rebuild it to target the specific Electron version using one of the [documented approaches](http://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules/).

Comment: Update: Tried installing the electron-rebuild and got a huge error, since it's too long going to create a new thread.

Comment: Here's the new thread with the error i'm currently having: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41042572/update-need-help-for-my-thesis-project-electron-express-sqlite3